cannot read properties of undefined ( reading ' map ')
I am trying to fetch data from the backend and display in the front end of my application. I am using fetch API and CORS is set up correctly at the backend.
When the component loads data is not displayed in the frontend so I added console.log as a way to debug and I realize that my
     'const data = await response.json()'
console.log(data)

promise gets fulfilled and shows in the console. When I also console.log the console.log( setData( data.dataProducts ));  I see undefined in the console.
I set a ternary operator on the map function to stop my app from crashing but before I did that, The error in the console is cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map').
My backend is fine as I test it on Thunder Client and it displays. I also went ahead to test on the browser by pasting this route: 'http://localhost:8080/data' and it also display my Jason data at the backend.
My questions are: Why is the set state undefined and why are the properties of map undefined? I really need your help. Please forgive me for code formatting. Thanks. My components:
const Shopstore = () => {
  const [dataProducts, setData] = useState([]);

  const url = "http://localhost:8080/data";

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchfunc = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(url);

        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error("network issues pls wait ");
        }
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log(data);
        console.log(setData(data.dataProducts));
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("error", error);
      }
    };

    fetchfunc();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="Shopstore mt-5">
      <Container>
        <Row>
          <Col md={10} className="big mt-3">
            {dataProducts ? (
              dataProducts.map((product) => {
                return <Listings key={product._id} {...product} />;
              })
            ) : (
              <p>no data</p>
            )}
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Shopstore;

//child component
const Listings = (products) => {
  const { image, heading, price, _id } = products;

  return (
    <div className="listings mt-3 mb-3">
      <Container>
        <Row>
          <Col md={4} id={_id}>
            <div className="card mx-auto" style={{ width: "250px" }}>
              <Card>
                <div className="image mx-auto ">
                  <Link to={`/shop/${products._id}`}>
                    <img
                      src={image}
                      alt=""
                      className="img-fluid"
                      style={{ width: "300px" }}
                    />
                  </Link>
                  <CardBody>
                    <div className="title">
                      <h5>{heading}</h5>
                    </div>
                    <div className="price">
                      <span>{price}</span>
                    </div>

                    <div className=" mx-auto">
                      <button className="mx-auto cartbutton">
                        Add to cart
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  </CardBody>
                </div>
              </Card>
            </div>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Listings


When I also console.log the console.log( setData( data.dataProducts )); I see undefined in the console. setData returns undefined, so that's normal. But what does console.log(data) display? Your code is expecting data to be an object with a dataProducts array, but apparently it's not.

Plz validate that dataProducts is present in the structure you are receiving from the API. Additionaly, you could initialize dataProducts to an empty array to avoid undefined issues

@Nicholas Tower Console.log(data) display an oblect. I mention this before. I can see my data in the console. How do I really fix this? I still do not understand why my setState is undefined..

@sharad paul. Can you please clarify your suggestion?

When you are setting data.dataProducts you are getting undefined. This suggests data object does not contain dataProducts. Validate if dataProducts exists in that log. const data = await response.json();         console.log(data);         console.log(setData(data.dataProducts));
